# Keep same page instance when going back on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

Hi i'm new to windows 8 development,
When i press the back-key in windows 8 ,the page is again instantiated. How to avoid it ?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Language? Development environment? Code? It's probably worth a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `this.NavigationCacheMode= NavigationCacheMode.Required;` in the page contructor to prevent Initialize to be called again.